# Qt WebEngineView: Проблема с длительной загрузкой WebGL проекта (экспортированного из Unity)

Tags: c++, qt, unity3d, webgl, qtwebengine

Возникла необходимость создания интерактивного просмотрщика 3D-моделей, который будет встраиваться в QML проект. Решено было пойти по такому пути - сам просмотрщик делать в Unity 2018 и оттуда экспортировать в виде WebGL проекта, который затем открывать в QML посредством WebEngineView (версия Qt 5.12.0). На данный момент видится пока такой путь.

Начал пробовать на малом и по минимуму, чтобы отладить механизм открытия.

В Unity, в качестве примера, была создана пустая сцена без объектов (только камера)...[image: Сцена в Unity проекте]

...и экспортирована в сборке WebGL (применена .gzip компрессия, размер сборки 2.3 Мб) [image: Build Settings в Unity]

Qt проект был взят из библиотеки примеров QtCreator ("WebEngine Widgets Minimal Example").

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWebEngineView>

QUrl commandLineUrlArgument()
{
    const QStringList args = QCoreApplication::arguments();
    for (const QString &arg : args.mid(1)) {
        if (!arg.startsWith(QLatin1Char('-')))
            return QUrl::fromUserInput(arg);
    }
    return QUrl(QStringLiteral("file:///F:/qt/test4Exp/index.html"));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QWebEngineView view;
    view.setUrl(commandLineUrlArgument());
    view.resize(1024, 750);
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

При открытии WebGL проекта в браузере Chrome все загружается очень быстро (мгновенно) [image: Открытие WebGL проекта в браузере Chrome]

При открытии WebGL проекта в WebEngineView проект загружается очень очень долго - примерно 5-6 минут...[image: Загрузка WebGL проекта в WebEngineView (в таком состоянии 5-6 минут)]

...но после загрузки работает без тормозов (проверял с загрузкой проекта сложной 3D-модели) [image: WebGL проект открытый в WebEngineView]

WebGL проект открывается с локального диска. Я пробовал различные варианты параметров экспорта из Unity (brotil компрессия, оптимизаци кода и др.). Пробовал также открытие WebGL проекта из под QML страницы. Разницы никакой. Скажите, в чем может быть проблема? Может быть применить какие-нибудь опции при сборке или применить QCoreApplication::setAttribute ??

Ниже прикладываю ссылки на проект Qt и WebGL проект.

[WebGL проект](https://ufile.io/20juwm74)

[Qt проект](https://ufile.io/lwgepets)

Comment: ну да. там большой бинарь. делайте на каком нибудь three.js для просмотрщика моделей там все есть и открываться будет намного быстрее

Comment: @StrangerintheQ а можно поподробнее?)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker про что конкретно, про three.js?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, я даже не совсем понял, почему бинарник на 2.3мб "большой"

Comment: @RiotBr3aker против 300кб-огромный, да и там wasm, боюсь а культях он не огонь

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, спасибо за совет, изучу))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем проблема решилась сама собой, после того, как запустил приложение не из под QtCreator, а из под exe файла. Вообще под exe файлом шустрее работает все. Видимо запуск и инициализация движка Unity тормозится QtCreator-ом. При работе приложения из под exe запуск WebGL проекта в WebEngineView происходит за 2-3 секунды (на стареньких ПК 7-9 сек).